# How do I stop the Odoo rich text editor for escaping <% %> in html edit mode?

Tags: odoo

I'm trying to edit the HTML output of the rich text editor and when I un focus it `<%` `%>` turns into `&lt;%` and `&gt;%`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must've not had my coffee when I asked this. You need it to scape because otherwise `<% if %>` would be treated as a tag and not show up in the normal edit mode.